# How to generate a link to a different Rails page and mark that specific item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I built out a couple of pages using a mixture of JS and HTML within a Rails app and it's ugly and repetitive. So I'm going back through attempting to do it the Rails way.

So I built out the controller, index page, and show page. I'm working on the order page for purchasing items. Basically I need to link an item on the index page to the order page.

I have the following that should work (doesn't but that's a whole other issue):

```
<%= link_to 'Order', order_books_path(@book) %>
```

These links are next to each book. Ideally when a person clicks on the book it goes to the order page which displays all the books and marks the book that was just clicked.

In my JS/HTML mash up I applied a variable that when present on page load it made the book active.

What's the best Rails way to do this?

EDIT: My controller is pretty minimal at this point and I just have:

```
class BooksController <ApplicationController
def index
 @book = Book.all
end

def order
 @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end

def show
 @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

I can just imagine that my order method is really wrong as well.

Comment: What do your controller and routes files look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on the `books#index` route, I'm assuming you have a full list of books you want to display. In that case, the following should work in your `books/index.html.erb`:

```
# books/index.html.erb
# @books is your list of books => [Book1, Book2, ...etc]

@books.each do |book|
  <div> <%= book.title %> </div>
  # other misc book info
  <%= link_to 'Order', order_books_path(book) %>
  # assuming the order_books_path is the correct route
end
```